# How to remove time from date

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my date picker i am getting date correct. This is my datepicker code

```
.datepicker({
              autoclose: true,
              todayHighlight: true,
              startDate: '+0d'
             })
```

This is my Controller code in this "Servicedate" getting date with default time 12:00:00 but in my datepicker value it is giving date and i don't required time.

```
public ActionResult GetServiceProviders(RankedServices.Entities.Admin.Services Services)
        {
            // if (Services != null && Services.SelectedServiceIds != null)
            int FutureDate = DateTime.Compare(Services.Servicedate, Convert.ToDateTime(Services.USdate));

            if (Services != null && (Services.SelectedServiceIds != null || Services.ServiceIds != null) && FutureDate >= 0)
            {
                if (Services.SelectedServiceIds != null)
                    Services.ServiceIds = string.Join(",", Services.SelectedServiceIds);

                //  Services.ServiceIds = string.Join(",", Services.SelectedServiceIds);

                if (Services.ServiceIds != "" && (Services.SubLocationID != "" || Services.Servicedate.Date != null))
                {
                    string UserID = "";
                    if (Session["UserID"] != null)
                    {
                        UserID = Session["UserID"].ToString();
                    }

                    Services.lstServiceProviders = ServiceDetails.GetServiceProviders(Services.SubLocationID, Services.ServiceIds.TrimEnd(','), UserID, Services.Servicedate.Date.ToString(), Services.Daymode, Services.ProviderID);

                    IEnumerable<RankedServices.Entities.Admin.Services> lstServices = ServiceDetails.GetServicesList(Services.SubLocationID.ToString());
                    ViewBag.SelectedServices = new MultiSelectList(lstServices, Services.SelectedServiceIds);

                    return View("ServicesList", Services);
                    //  return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("guestsearch", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("guestsearch", "Home"); // if none are selected re-direct to Guest-Search
            }
        }
```

This is my model for service date:

```
public DateTime Servicedate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do you have a timer picker component on the date picker? or is it a *date* picker?  What are you expecting the *"exact"* time to be on the date that is picked by the user?

Comment: You may need something like this (date time picker) http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: var dateNow = new Date();
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate:dateNow
        });

Comment: in my datepicker i want only date and don't requried time

Comment: and i am using only datepicker and it is not a datetimepicker

Comment: $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

Comment: did you checked my answer @ArunRaju

Comment: in my code also iam getting only date but in my model it is changing to date and time.and thank u for ur answer

Comment: Your (original) question and comments and final comment seem to be backwards. Can you confirm your issue is:  you have a `DateTime` in C# and when you show this in the UI, it's showing with date and time but you only want it to show with date.   If that's the case, change the format of the datepicker.

Comment: In the UI i.e datepicker iam getting date only and iam getting that date to controller it is taking as date and as well as default time i.e.12:00:00 but i don't need time in my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification in comments:

> In the UI i.e datepicker I am getting date only and I am getting that date to controller it is taking as date and as well as default time (12:00:00) - but I don't need time in my controller

In your C# controller, you have a `DateTime`- this, as the name implies, always has a Date *and* a Time.

To get just the date part, you'd expect to take `.Date` (as in `DateTime.Now.Date`) - however, this is also a datetime, so gives you a date+time, with default time.   You would use `.Date` when you did have a time (as from `.Now`) and wanted to discard the time part.

The issue is not that you have a time part, but in **how you use the DateTime object**.

```
... Services.Servicedate.Date.ToString() ...
```

You need to format the datetime at this point rather than rely on the default ".ToString()" (which includes the time part).  To do this, you can use one of the built-in formats:

```
Services.Servicedate.ToShortDateString()   // locale dependent, 4/13/2017 or 13/4/2017
Services.Servicedate.ToLongDateString()    // Thursday, April 13, 2017
```

or, if these do not provide the fomat you're interested in (or that's compatible with your service call), then use a custom format, eg:

```
Services.Servicedate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")  // 2017-04-13
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `Date Format`

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' });
```

Answer (score 0):

For that You need to add date format to datepicker like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {              
           $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                 format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'              // Add DateFormat
           });
        });      
    </script>
```

For Details Refer [**DatePicker**](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)